# Django custom JSONField has no attribute 'name'

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, orm

I got `JSONFields` that I have to `encode` and `decode` every trip, the problem is I got few of them, so I'm trying to make a custom field like this:

```
    class JSONField(models.JSONField):
        """A Field to encode & decode JSONField."""

        def __init__(self, default=dict, encoder=None, decoder=None):
            self.encoder = encoder
            self.decoder = decoder
            self.default = default

        def get_prep_value(self, value: Any) -> Any:
            if value is None:
                return value
            return json.dumps(value, default=self.default, cls=self.encoder)

        def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
            if value is None:
                return value
            return json.loads(value, cls=self.decoder)
```

But when I use it on the model

```
    class Employee(models.Model):
        time_log = JSONField()
```

I get this error `AttributeError: 'JSONField' object has no attribute 'name'`

```
    File "/Users/mac/Documents/Payroll/payroll/models.py", line 106, in <module>
        class Employee(models.Model):
    File "/Users/mac/Documents/Payroll/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 161, in __new__
        new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
    File "/Users/mac/Documents/Payroll/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
        value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    File "/Users/mac/Documents/Payroll/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 781, in contribute_to_class
        self.set_attributes_from_name(name)
    File "/Users/mac/Documents/Payroll/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 768, in set_attributes_from_name
        self.name = self.name or name
    AttributeError: 'JSONField' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__init__` is incomplete. You only define the fields `self.default`, `self.encoder`, and `self.decoder` and not the others that should also be present such as `self.null`, `self.blank`, `self._unique`, etc. which are supposed to be attributes of any Django model field, whether they are just None or has a value, they should still be attributes that can be accessed by its class' objects. Your custom class lacks this attributes thus the error upon accessing them.

Actually, the supposed usage of `models.JSONField` should include arbitrary `**options` (named `**kwargs` in code) which you are lacking in your custom defined class.

So your custom JSONField should look like:

```
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

    class JSONField(models.JSONField):
        """A minimal Field to encode & decode JSONField."""

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        def get_prep_value(self, value: Any)-> Any:
            if value is None:
                return value
            return json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        def from_db_value(self, value: Any, expression, connection) -> Any:
            if value is None:
                return value
            return json.loads(value, cls=None)

        def to_python(self, value: Any)-> Any:
            if isinstance(value, JSONField):
                return value

            if value is None:
                return value

            return json.loads(value, cls=None)
```

Read more here:

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#field-options)

[Django code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L131)

Comment: That's right! I got it working with kwargs and subclassing to_python. Can I edit the answer and post a simple version of your explanation?